# Regex that validate for a number with length 8, 11, 13 followed by an optional + symbol

Tags: regex

I have following regex

```
^\+?[0-9]*$
```

I want to validate for a number with length 8, 11, 13 followed by an optional + symbol but don't know how to add lengths 8,11,13 in it.

If + symbol is included the length  of whole string must be 8,11 or 13

Comment: Try `^\+(?:\d{8}|\d{11}|\d{13})$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regex matches an optional plus sign and a digit `[0-9]` repeated zero or more times using the asterix `*`. The regex could also match an empty string or `+1`

You could use a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) like `{8}`, `{11}` and `{13}`.

[`^(?:\+(?:[0-9]{12}|[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{7})|(?:[0-9]{13}|[0-9]{11}|[0-9]{8}))$`](https://regex101.com/r/rGSAyM/4)

Match either a plus sign `+` followed by the digits with the quantifiers for `{12}`, `{10}` and `{8}`.

Or match the digits using a quantifier for `{13}`, `{11}` and `{9}`

Comment: thank you for answer, If + symbol is included the length  of whole string must be 8,11 or 13

Comment: @DMP Then an option might be to match a plus sign with 12 digits, or 13 digits without a plus sign. Then you could also do this for the other digits. I have updated the regex in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use double conditionnal :
`^\+[0-9]{8}([0-9]{3}[0-9]{2}?)?$`

**Explanation :**

`^` Start of the string
`\+` escaped `+` symbol
`[0-9]{8}` It will go for 8 digit,
`([0-9]{3}` then 3 more digits
`[0-9]{2}` then 2 more digits
`?)` which is optionnal
`?` the whole part after 8 digits is also optionnal
`$` end of the string